# Button to vibrate makes android app force close

Tags: java, android, forceclose, vibration

Im just making a simple app that will vibrate when the button is clicked, but for some reason when i click the button the app says it unexpectedly stopped and needed to force close, below is the source code to the main java file and i have used the android vibrate permission in my manifest. can someone tell me why every time I click the vibrate button it           gives me the error  that it unexpectedly stopped?

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.test.MESSAGE";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

/* Called when the user clicks the button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void vibrateMe() {


    Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    vibrate.vibrate(500);


}

public void stopVibrating(Vibrator vibrate) {

        vibrate.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add Stacktrace, you probably didn't add vibration permission.

Comment: i used the vibrate permission but still same keeps happening

Comment: Are you sure it's the vibrator? Check logcat, it usually tells you which line of code is the problem. You might also be losing the reference to vibrate. Where does vibrateMe() and stopVibrating get called?

Comment: How did you set the listener to the button?

Comment: the vibrating methods get called by this: android:onClick="vibrateMe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your `vibrateMe()` to `vibrateMe(View v)` if you use `android:onClick="vibrateMe"`

> For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must
>   declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context
>   (typically, your Activity).

[Check the developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick)

Answer (score 0):

public void stopVibrating(Vibrator vibrate) {

```
    vibrate.cancel();
}
```

remove this and then check.